# Open a form when it's name is a string

Tags: vb.net

I have a collection of forms named after weekdays, and I want to make my application open the determined form for that day. I've been scouring the internet since yesterday trying to find a working solution to no avail. I am using `Format(Now, "ddd")` to determine what day of the week it is. Thank you!

Comment: And how do you have named your form classes?

Comment: I have my forms named the same as the Format result, so for example, if it is Monday, I want to open the form named "mon"

Comment: Simply check for the name and open the corresponding form. This can be easily done with a `Select...Case` statement.

Comment: It's still not clear how you are referring to your forms. Remember: forms are just Classes, and like any Class you can have multiple instances of a form. So when you say you have a form named after a weekday, it's not clear yet whether you mean you have a variable with that name referring to an instance of a form, or whether you're talking about the type (Class name) of the form. If the latter, do you already have a specific instance of the class you need? If the former, do the variables refer to instances of the same form class or different classes?

Comment: Some [more options here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66495492/2330053)...

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 ways to do this.

```
'Using default instance
Private Sub OpenForm(DayOfWeekString As String)
    Select Case DayOfWeekString
        Case "Monday"
            Monday.Show()
        Case "Tuesday"
            Tuesday.Show()
            'etc.
        Case Else
            MessageBox.Show("Not a valid form name.")
    End Select
End Sub

'Creating a specific instance
Private Sub OpenForm(DayOfWeekString As String)
    Dim frm As Form
    Select Case DayOfWeekString
        Case "Monday"
            frm = New Monday() 'Creates a new instance of the Monday class
        Case "Tuesday"
            frm = New Tuesday()
            'etc.
        Case Else
            MessageBox.Show("Not a valid form name.")
            Return
    End Select
    frm.Show()
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

More options suggested by @Joel in comments.

Using a Dictionary.

```
Private FormDictionay As New Dictionary(Of String, Form) From {{"Monday", Monday}, {"Tuesday", Tuesday}}

Private Sub Openform3(DayOfWeekString As String)
    Dim frm = FormDictionay(DayOfWeekString)
    frm.Show()
End Sub

'Returns the proper form to open in the calling code.
Private Function GetFormFromStringOrToday(Optional DayOfWeek As String = "Get Day") As Form
    If DayOfWeek = "Get Day" Then
        DayOfWeek = Now.DayOfWeek.ToString
    End If
    Return FormDictionay(DayOfWeek)
End Function
```

Comment: I might add a third option that adds the forms to a dictionary, and a fourth for an overloaded method that merely returns the appropriate form instance based on a string argument or current date (if called with no argument)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Added as per your suggestion.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, the `Dictionary` option would certainly work but the downside would be that you would create all form instances when you create the `Dictionary`, even if some of them will never be used. That may not be a big deal but it's something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to refer to types by name as text, Reflection is an option. It's generally fairly slow but if there's not much code then that would be unlikely to be noticed. In your case, you could do this:

```vb
Private Sub DisplayForm(name As String)
    'Get a Type object representing the desired form type.
    Dim t = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("Your.Namespace.Here." & name)

    'Get the parameterless constructor for the type.
    Dim c = t.GetConstructor({})

    'Invoke the constructor to create an instance.
    Dim f = DirectCast(c.Invoke(Nothing), Form)

    f.Show()
End Sub
```

The `Assembly.GetType` method requires the fully-qualified name, so you need to specify the namespace the form types are a member of. That will likely be the root namespace for your project, which will likely be the same as your project name.